# mongoTemplate returning unformatted object

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I have following aggregation query method:-

```
public List<String> fetchRelativeIds(String externalId) {
        ProjectionOperation projectionOperation = project().and("ancestors._id")
                .concatArrays("descendants._id").as("weNeedRelations").andInclude("_id");

        MatchOperation filterByIds = Aggregation.match(new Criteria("externalIds.fenergo").is(externalId));

        Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(filterByIds, projectionOperation);

        return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, Master.class.getSimpleName(), String.class).getMappedResults();

    }
```

This gives me output as below:-

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5aafb705f3fabe7c915bca14"} , "weNeedRelations" : [ { "$oid" : "5aafb718f3fabe7c915bca1f"} , { "$oid" : "5aafb719f3fabe7c915bca23"} , { "$oid" : "5aafb6fbf3fabe7c915bca10"}]}
```

I just want the `$oid` value part as string nothing else. E.g.

```
 { "_id" : "5aafb705f3fabe7c915bca14" , "weNeedRelations" : [ "5aafb718f3fabe7c915bca1f" ,  "5aafb719f3fabe7c915bca23", "5aafb6fbf3fabe7c915bca10"]}
```

How could I do that?

Comment: Are you talking about this part?? "weNeedRelations" : [ { "$oid" : "5aafb718f3fabe7c915bca1f"}....

Comment: for both `weNeedRelations` and `_id`

Comment: What do you mean by this: "I just want the $oid value part as string nothing else"
Your question is not clear!
Show us the output format you want

Comment: updated @Afridi